# Android - creating a few frame layout and align them with Gravity programmatically

Tags: java, android, gravity

I have an array of results and i want to display each one of them in a different FrameLayout. My activity already contains a ScrollView that contains a RelativeLayout. I am using a 'for' to create each FrameLayout but right now every one of the results' parameters displayed on the same spot - This is probably because the gravity parameters are not set correctly.

This is my code:

```
         for (int i = 0; i < results.length; ++i) {
                LayoutParams textViewsLayoutParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        Gravity.CLIP_VERTICAL);
                LayoutParams dividerLayoutParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1,
                        Gravity.CLIP_VERTICAL);
                LayoutParams frameLayoutParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.CLIP_VERTICAL);
                frameLayoutParams.setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5);
                //Initializing text views
                TextView domain = new TextView(SinglePhotoResults.this);
                domain.setText(results[i].getDomain());
                domain.setTextSize(22);
                domain.setGravity(Gravity.CLIP_VERTICAL);
                domain.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#1A1AFF"));
                domain.setLayoutParams(textViewsLayoutParams);

                TextView url = new TextView(SinglePhotoResults.this);
                url.setText(results[i].getURL());
                url.setTextSize(22);
                url.setGravity(Gravity.CLIP_VERTICAL);
                url.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#00CC00"));
                url.setLayoutParams(textViewsLayoutParams);

                View divider = new View(SinglePhotoResults.this);
                divider.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00ff00"));
                divider.setLayoutParams(dividerLayoutParams);

                TextView percents = new TextView(SinglePhotoResults.this);
                Integer percentage = results[i].getPrecents();
                percents.setText(percentage.toString());
                percents.setTextSize(22);
                percents.setGravity(Gravity.CLIP_VERTICAL);
                percents.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
                percents.setLayoutParams(textViewsLayoutParams);

                TextView copiedWords = new TextView(SinglePhotoResults.this);
                Integer copiedWordsNum = results[i].getNumberOfCopiedWords();
                copiedWords.setText(copiedWordsNum.toString());
                copiedWords.setTextSize(22);
                copiedWords.setGravity(Gravity.CLIP_VERTICAL);
                copiedWords.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
                copiedWords.setLayoutParams(textViewsLayoutParams);
                //Initializing frame layout
                FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(SinglePhotoResults.this);
                frameLayout.setLayoutParams(frameLayoutParams);
                frameLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
                frameLayout.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
                frameLayout.setForegroundGravity(Gravity.CLIP_VERTICAL);
                //Adding views to FrameLayout
                frameLayout.addView(domain);
                frameLayout.addView(url);
                frameLayout.addView(divider);
                frameLayout.addView(percents);
                frameLayout.addView(copiedWords);
                ////Adding frameLayout to relativeLayout
                RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.singlePhotoResultRelativeLayout);
                relativeLayout.addView(frameLayout);
            }
```

I want it to be displayed one rectangle after another.
How can i set the Gravity parameters correctly of the FrameLayouts and inside it?

Comment: one after another? `LinearLayout` is your friend then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using Relative layout you should use LinearLayout. If you still want to use Relative layout you need to specify below which element you put your next element.
(I would suggest moving to listview instead).